# Xamarin Android name clash when overriding methods in FloatingActionButton.Behavior

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm implementing a FAB in my application using the support design library and following [this guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons) to add the disappearing/reappearing when scrolling behaviour. I've converted the ScrollAwareFABBehavior class provided to C# but I get the following compiler error.

```
error: name clash: onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout,View,View,View,int) in ScrollAwareFABBehavior and onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout,V,View,View,int) in Behavior have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
public boolean onStartNestedScroll (android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout p0, android.view.View p1, android.view.View p2, android.view.View p3, int p4)
where V is a type-variable:
V extends View declared in class Behavior Project.Droid E:\VS Projects\Project\Project.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\md5fa22044078b50743372e010f51d93dc4\ScrollAwareFABBehavior.java
```

Here is the converted class:

```
public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior : FloatingActionButton.Behavior
{
    public ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) {
    }

    public override bool OnStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, Java.Lang.Object child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.ScrollAxisVertical ||
            base.OnStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
    }

    public override void OnNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, Java.Lang.Object child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        base.OnNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);

        var fab = (FloatingActionButton)child;

        if (dyConsumed > 0 && fab.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible) {
            fab.Hide();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && fab.Visibility != ViewStates.Visible) {
            fab.Show();
        }
    }

}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error as I'm just overriding two methods from the base class, is this something I've done wrong or a bug in Xamarin Android?
I've created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/ChrisWay/68faab72405bb528dcfb) showing the Java code that is shown when double clicking the error in Visual Studio,

Comment: Interestingly, the C# override has type Java.Lang.Object for parameter child, whereas the Java version use type View.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get past this by using the parent class `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` instead of `FloatingActionButton.Behavior`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html

I have gone ahead and filed a bug on this issue for the time being:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34777

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that you should take care of is to either register the class which will extend `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` or (which is what I do) in your xml file where you declare your floating action button you should write something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_behavior="md566409b1cfad53f1139d359f4a87074d2.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#3f51b5"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/floating_arrow" />
```

Notice the attribute layout_behavior. The string before your class name is found at your project's folder in the location `obj/debug/android/src` and then check all the folders with similar name like the one here to see which one contains your `ScrollAwareFABBehavior` class.